# Can I change colors within a \draw?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I was hoping to draw something like the following:

[image]

And I can by using `\draw` twice:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1mm]
\draw[fill=red](0,0)rectangle(4,4)--(8,8);
\draw[fill=blue](8,8)rectangle(12,12);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However I was hoping to do this with a single `\draw`.  I can do this easily if both of the squares were the same color. à la,

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1mm,fill=red]
\draw(0,0)rectangle(4,4)--(8,8)rectangle(12,12);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But I can't figure out how to get two differently colored shapes with a single draw.  Is there a way to change colors partway through a draw?

Comment: Is it an alternative to use nodes instead of `rectangle`s?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I am not sure what you mean,  I would like to draw rectangles, if this can be attained with nodes I am interested.

Comment: According to the pgfmanual, `\draw` is `\path[draw]`, `rectangle` is a (sub)path, and colour options anywhere in the path apply to the whole path, with the last option winning.  So working with nodes is the way to go.

Comment: What is the advantage of doing this in one draw? -something to do with line joints?

Comment: @hpekristiansen I am trying to code golf in tikz. :p

Answer (score 9):

You could perhaps draw a line from `(0,0)` to `(4,4)` and add a `node` at each end.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1mm,every node/.style={outer sep=0pt,minimum size=2cm}]
\draw(0,0) node[draw=black,fill=red,below left] {} -- (4,4) node[draw=black,fill=blue,below left] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try with customized arrow tips (from `arrows.meta`)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[{Turned Square[open, fill=red, length=1cm]}
      -
      {Turned Square[open, fill=blue, length=1cm]}] 
      (0,0)--(4,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]